# Does limit of $|x|^{1/|y|}$ exist at $(0,0) ?$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Does limit of $|x|^{1/|y|}$ exist at $(0,0) ?$

This limit is zero along any path I've taken.
But I am not able find out if the limit exists in general.

Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: which paths have you taken?

Comment: It’s like $0^ \infty$, why would it give any problem? I mean, what is bothering you? Maybe I am not seeing something

Comment: @peek-a-boo $0^\infty$ is not an indeterminate form. It's $0$.

Comment: @bjorn93 yes of course, that was indeed a very silly mistake (for some reason my brain did a different calculation)

Comment: As a hint, note that by definition, $|x|^{1/|y|} = \exp\left( (\ln|x|)/|y| \right)$. What happens to $ln|x|$ as $x \to 0$? What happens to $|y|$ as $y \to 0$? What happens to the quotient (lol this is where I initially made a mistake)? What can you now conclude about the whole expression?

Answer (score 0):

If $|y|, |x|<1$, then $|x|^{\frac{1}{|y|}} <|x|$. So for any path going to $(0,0)$, the expression is eventually bounded by $|x|$, which along the path goes to $0$, so the limit is indeed $0$.